# Java POS printer error

Tags: java, javapos

I'm novice to Java, and I'm developing POS application using java.

I bought an Epson POS printer for this project. Printer model is `EPSON TM-U220.`

I've installed `JavaPos` and, my code snippet as follows. but when running I get this error.

Appreciate if anyone could help me with this problem.

---

```
run:
jpos.JposException: Service does not exist in loaded JCL registry
StarReceiptTest finished.
    at jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager.createConnection(SimpleServiceManager.java:179)
    at jpos.loader.JposServiceLoader.findService(JposServiceLoader.java:154)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(BaseJposControl.java:481)
    at StarReceiptTest.main(StarReceiptTest.java:54)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

---

```
import jpos.JposConst;
import jpos.JposException;
import jpos.POSPrinter;
import jpos.POSPrinterConst;

import jpos.util.JposPropertiesConst;

public class StarReceiptTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args){   
        /*
        If you want to place the jpos.xml file elsewhere on your local file system then uncomment the
        following line and specify the full path to jpos.xml.

        If you want to place the jpos.xml file on a webserver for access over the internet then uncomment
        the second System.setProperty line below and specify the full URL to jpos.xml.
        */
        //C:\Users\Udayanga\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Jpos_Sample\src
        //System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, "jpos.xml");
        System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, "C:\\Users\\Udayanga\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Jpos_Sample\\src\\jpos.xml");
        //System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_URL_PROP_NAME, "http://some-where-remote.com/jpos.xml");

        // constants defined for convience sake (could be inlined)
        String ESC    = ((char) 0x1b) + "";
        String LF     = ((char) 0x0a) + "";
        String SPACES = "                                                                      ";

        // instantiate a new jpos.POSPrinter object
        POSPrinter printer = new POSPrinter();
        //ESDPRT001 = Port
        try
        {
            // open the printer object according to the entry names defined in jpos.xml
            //printer.open("startsp");

            //ESDPRT001
            printer.open("TM-U220");

            // claim exclsive usage of the printer object
            printer.claim(1);

            // enable the device for input and output
            printer.setDeviceEnabled(true);

            // set map mode to metric - all dimensions specified in 1/100mm units
            printer.setMapMode(POSPrinterConst.PTR_MM_METRIC);  // unit = 1/100 mm - i.e. 1 cm = 10 mm = 10 * 100 units

            do
            {
                // poll for printer status
                //   a javax.swing based application would be best to both poll for status
                //   AND register for asynchronous StatusUpdateEvent notification
                //   see the JavaPOS specification for details on this

                // check if the cover is open
                if (printer.getCoverOpen() == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("printer.getCoverOpen() == true");

                    // cover open so do not attempt printing
                    break;
                }

                // check if the printer is out of paper
                if (printer.getRecEmpty() == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("printer.getRecEmpty() == true");

                    // the printer is out of paper so do not attempt printing
                    break;
                }

                // being a transaction
                //   transaction mode causes all output to be buffered
                //   once transaction mode is terminated, the buffered data is
                //   outputted to the printer in one shot - increased reliability
                printer.transactionPrint(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, POSPrinterConst.PTR_TP_TRANSACTION);

                if (printer.getCapRecBitmap() == true){
                    // print an image file
                    try
                    {
                        printer.printBitmap(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "star.gif", POSPrinterConst.PTR_BM_ASIS, POSPrinterConst.PTR_BM_CENTER);
                    }
                    catch (JposException e)
                    {
                        if (e.getErrorCode () != JposConst.JPOS_E_NOEXIST)
                        {
                            // error other than file not exist - propogate it
                            throw e;
                        }

                        // image file not found - ignore this error & proceed
                    }
                }

                // call printNormal repeatedly to generate out receipt
                //   the following JavaPOS-POSPrinter control code sequences are used here
                //   ESC + "|cA"          -> center alignment
                //   ESC + "|4C"          -> double high double wide character printing
                //   ESC + "|bC"          -> bold character printing
                //   ESC + "|uC"          -> underline character printing
                //   ESC + "|rA"          -> right alignment

                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, ESC + "|cA" + ESC + "|4C" + ESC + "|bC" + "Star Grocer"     + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, ESC + "|cA" + ESC + "|bC" +               "Shizuoka, Japan" + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, ESC + "|cA" + ESC + "|bC" +               "054-555-5555"    + LF);

                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, ESC + "|uC" + "Qnty Unit Tx Description" + SPACES.substring(0, printer.getRecLineChars() - "Qnty Unit Tx Description".length()) + LF);

                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               "   1  830    Soba Noodles"        + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               "   1  180    Daikon Radish"       + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               "   1  350    Shouyu Soy Sauce"    + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               "   1   80    Negi Green Onions"   + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               "   1  100    Wasabi Horse Radish" + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               "   2  200 Tx Hashi Chop Sticks"   + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, LF);

                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               ESC + "|rA" +               "Subtotal:  2160" + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               ESC + "|rA" +               "Tax:         24" + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               ESC + "|rA" + ESC + "|bC" + "Total:     2184" + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               ESC + "|rA" +               "Tender:    2200" + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,               ESC + "|rA" + ESC + "|bC" + "Change:      16" + LF);
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, LF);

                if (printer.getCapRecBarCode() == true)
                {
                    // print a Code 3 of 9 barcode with the data "123456789012" encoded
                    //   the 10 * 100, 60 * 100 parameters below specify the barcode's height and width
                    //   in the metric map mode (1cm tall, 6cm wide)
                    printer.printBarCode(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "123456789012", POSPrinterConst.PTR_BCS_Code39, 10 * 100, 60 * 100, POSPrinterConst.PTR_BC_CENTER, POSPrinterConst.PTR_BC_TEXT_BELOW);
                }

                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, ESC + "|cA" + ESC + "|4C" + ESC + "|bC" + "Thank you" + LF);

                // the ESC + "|100fP" control code causes the printer to execute a paper cut
                //   after feeding to the cutter position
                printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, ESC + "|100fP");

                // terminate the transaction causing all of the above buffered data to be sent to the printer
                printer.transactionPrint(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, POSPrinterConst.PTR_TP_NORMAL);

                // exit our printing loop
            } while (false);
        }
        catch(JposException e)
        {
            // display any errors that come up
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            // close the printer object
            try
            {
                printer.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        System.out.println("StarReceiptTest finished.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Here is the jpos.xml file

```
    <!--Other non JavaPOS required property (mostly vendor properties and bus specific properties i.e. RS232 )-->
    <prop name="Halftone" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PhysicalPrinterName" type="String" value="TM-U220"/>
    <prop name="NVRAMControlLevel" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="Stamp" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="OutputCompleteType" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="StatusThreadInterval" type="String" value="100"/>
    <prop name="OutputTimeout" type="String" value="500"/>
    <prop name="PortType" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="OutputBufferSize" type="String" value="65536"/>
    <prop name="UsedNVRAM" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="FirmRecordLog" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="ReceiveTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="SlpReverseEject" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PortName" type="String" value="TM-U220"/>
    <prop name="OfflineRetryIntervalTime" type="String" value="25"/>
    <prop name="DefaultSlpClampTime" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="epson.trace.file" type="String" value="trace.log"/>
    <prop name="AsyncProcessingSize" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="KanjiTwoWaysPrint" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PulseStep" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="PortInterfaceName" type="String" value="USB"/>
    <prop name="OutPipe" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="U375Compatible" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PortNameType" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="preCutterFunction" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="epson.tracing" type="String" value="false"/>
    <prop name="epson.trace.max.size" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="RecPaperSize" type="String" value="76"/>
    <prop name="DeviceDesc" type="String" value="EPSON TM-U220D POSPrinter"/>
    <prop name="PageModeExt" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="SupportStatistics" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="FirmProgressRange" type="String" value="10"/>
    <prop name="OutputErrorOption" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="SupportFirmware" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InputTimeout" type="String" value="100"/>
    <prop name="AutoPowerOff" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="SlpMoreColumns" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="RecPaperType" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="MemorySwitch" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="ReadThreadInterval" type="String" value="-1"/>
    <prop name="QueuingOfflineTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="InitializeThreadTime" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="TwoColor" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="TwoByteCharacter" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="FirmLogFileSize" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="Peeler" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InPipe" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="ConfigurationFile" type="String" value="epson/xml/Setting/TM-U220DSetting.xml"/>
    <prop name="Custom1Color" type="String" value="0xFF0000"/>
    <prop name="preEndorseFunction" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="Upos.Spec_c" type="String" value="false"/>
    <prop name="FirmNotifyAllProgressEvents" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InitializeResponseTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="ReceiveRetryTime" type="String" value="25"/>
    <prop name="PrinterTransmitTimeout" type="String" value="30000"/>
    <prop name="RecMoreColumns" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="UsedInterCharacterSet" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="WriteThreadInterval" type="String" value="-1"/>
    <prop name="preORCBFunction" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="RecNearEndSensor" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="LogObject" type="String" value=""/>
    <prop name="Cutter" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PhysicalDevice" type="String" value="TM-U220D"/>
    <prop name="UsedPeeler" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="FirmLogFileName" type="String" value="Firmware.log"/>
    <prop name="InputBufferSize" type="String" value="4096"/>
    <prop name="TransmitTimeout" type="String" value="5000"/>
    <prop name="OfflineCount" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="TransmitRetryTime" type="String" value="100"/>
    <prop name="DirectIOEventTimeout" type="String" value="5000"/>
```

Comment: Tips: String ESC = "\u001b"; `c == true`can be `c` and `c == false` can be `!c` (not c).

Comment: Look at line 54 (do you see that line in the stacktrace of the error?). There is the cause. If that is the line `getCoverOpen()` then it seems that is not detectable here. Comment the code out.

Comment: Yes I get the error when executing line 54. Please help me..!! 

It says...
run: jpos.JposException: Service does not exist in loaded JCL registry

Comment: Put that info in the question, net everyone reads all small letter comments. with the line. (I cannot help further.)

Comment: I've solved it my own :) and now it's working fine. Thanks Joop for trying to help me

Comment: Hi. I am trying to delevop a javaPOS app myself but i don't find the jar to implement in Eclipse. Can you please tell my where did you find it ?

Comment: @Ann, I found it somewhere at http://www.javapos.com/index.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved it my own :) and now it's working fine. Thanks Joop for trying to help me.

Here is the solution worked for me.

1. Setup Printer drivers executing APD_455dE.exe
2. Setup Epson_JavaPOS_ADK_11317
3. Generate Jpos.xml Using SetupPOS.exe (Usually located in C:\Program Files\EPSON\JavaPOS\SetupPOS\SetupPOS.exe)
4. Save Jpos.xml in your src folder
5. Add following jar files to your project
   epsonJposService182.jar
   epsonJposServiceCommon.jar
   jpos18.jar
   xercesImpl.jar
   xml-apis.jar
6. Specify the Jpos.xml file to your project using following code
   System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, "D:\Test\Jpos_Sample\src\jpos.xml");
7. Ready to go...!!!!

If any one need further assistance regarding POS printer issues contact me. I'll try my best to help you guys.

Comment: @KostasC - Try looking into {your_jre_install_path}/jre6/lib/ext folder for those jar files.